# Rtools issues on older version of R - can't install packages from source

Tags: r, path, rtools

Hi I'm having problems installing packages from source in R.  I just got a new work machine, we're using version 3.5.3 of R which is obviously not up to date, but it works with the existing reporting that we have in place.  I can install binary packages for the time being but I need to install a certain package from source in order to access the functions I need from it.

When I got the laptop I installed rtools35 which is the compatible version of Rtools for this version of R.  However, I just saw that they installed rtools40 before shipping the laptop to me, and now I guess there's 2 versions of Rtools on this machine?  After some digging around I found out that this can cause some of the issues, but none of the solutions I've seen have fixed anything for me.

Below are the 2 folders where the different versions of RTools were installed to, as far as I'm aware Rtools refers to rtools35 (the one I need to be using). I've also read there can be problems if you rename rtools or if you move the default location of it (i don't think I did either of those things).

C:/Rtools

C:/rtools40

Below is the code I've tried putting in my home .Rprofile to explicitly state the path to the version of rtools that I need for R 3.5.3, but it doesn't fix my issue or allow me to install packages from source.

```
Sys.setenv(PATH=paste("C:/Rtools/bin",Sys.getenv("PATH"),sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(BINPREF="C:/Rtools/mingw_$(WIN)/bin/")
```

Also double checked to make sure the necessary files are in Rtools\bin and that Rtools is in my PATH.

```
Sys.which(c('make', 'gcc'))

"C:\\Rtools\\bin\\make.exe"  "C:\\Rtools\\bin\\gcc.exe"
```

```
Sys.getenv('PATH')

"C:/Rtools/bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\Rtools\\bin;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Gpg4win\\..\\GnuPG\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\bin\\rpostback;C:\\Program Files\\RStudio\\bin\\postback"
```

Double checking that R can find Rtools

```
devtools::find_rtools(T)

Scanning R CMD config CC...
cc_path: C:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc 
install_path: C:/Rtools 
Found compatible gcc from R CMD config CC
[1] TRUE
```

Here's my session info

```
session_info()

setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
 os       Windows 10 x64              
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  English_United States.1252  
 ctype    English_United States.1252  
 tz       America/Los_Angeles         
 date     2021-06-22                  

- Packages -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package       * version date       lib source        
 askpass         1.1     2019-01-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 assertthat      0.2.1   2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 base64enc       0.1-3   2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.2)
 cachem          1.0.5   2021-05-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 callr           3.7.0   2021-04-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 cellranger      1.1.0   2016-07-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 cli             2.5.0   2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 crayon          1.4.1   2021-02-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 curl            4.3.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 DBI             1.1.1   2021-01-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 desc            1.3.0   2021-03-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 devtools      * 2.4.2   2021-06-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 dplyr           1.0.6   2021-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ellipsis        0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 fansi           0.5.0   2021-05-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 fastmap         1.1.0   2021-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 fs              1.5.0   2020-07-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 gargle          1.1.0   2021-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 generics        0.1.0   2020-10-31 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 glue            1.4.2   2020-08-27 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 gmailr          1.0.0   2019-08-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 googledrive     1.0.1   2020-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 googlesheets4   0.3.0   2021-03-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 httr            1.4.2   2020-07-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 jsonlite        1.7.2   2020-12-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 lifecycle       1.0.0   2021-02-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 magrittr        2.0.1   2020-11-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 memoise         2.0.0   2021-01-26 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 openssl         1.4.4   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pillar          1.6.1   2021-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgbuild        1.2.0   2020-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgconfig       2.0.3   2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 pkgload         1.2.1   2021-04-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 prettyunits     1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 processx        3.5.2   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 ps              1.6.0   2021-02-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 purrr           0.3.4   2020-04-17 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 R6              2.5.0   2020-10-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 remotes         2.4.0   2021-06-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rlang           0.4.11  2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rprojroot       2.0.2   2020-11-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 rstudioapi      0.13    2020-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 sessioninfo     1.1.1   2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 testthat        3.0.2   2021-02-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tibble          3.1.2   2021-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 tidyselect      1.1.1   2021-04-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 usethis       * 2.0.1   2021-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 utf8            1.2.1   2021-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 vctrs           0.3.8   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)
 withr           2.4.2   2021-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.5.3)

[1] C:/Users/Jacob Yablonski/Documents/R/win-library/3.5
[2] C:/Program Files/R/R-3.5.3/library
```

Here's what trying to install a package from source looks like.

```
install.packages('kableExtra', dependencies = TRUE, type = 'source')


* installing *source* package 'kableExtra' ...
** package 'kableExtra' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
  converting help for package 'kableExtra'
    finding HTML links ... done
    add_footnote                            html  
    add_header_above                        html  
    add_indent                              html  
    as_image                                html  
    auto_index                              html  
    cell_spec                               html  
    collapse_rows                           html  
    column_spec                             html  
    footnote                                html  
    footnote_marker_number                  html  
    graphics_helpers                        html  
    group_rows                              html  
    header_separate                         html  
    html_dependency_bsTable                 html  
    html_dependency_kePrint                 html  
    html_dependency_lightable               html  
    kableExtra-package                      html  
    kableExtra_latex_packages               html  
    kable_as_image                          html  
    kable_as_xml                            html  
    kable_classic                           html  
    kable_styling                           html  
    kbl                                     html  
Rd warning: C:/Users/Jacob Yablonski/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpcl12FV/R.INSTALL18206c232499/kableExtra/man/kbl.Rd:70: file link 'opts_current' in package 'knitr' does not exist and so has been treated as a topic
    landscape                               html  
    linebreak                               html  
    listify_args                            html  
    magic_mirror                            html  
    make_inline_plot                        html  
    reexports                               html  
    remove_column                           html  
    rmd_format                              html  
    row_spec                                html  
    save_kable                              html  
    scroll_box                              html  
    spec_angle                              html  
    spec_boxplot                            html  
    spec_color                              html  
    spec_font_size                          html  
    spec_hist                               html  
    spec_image                              html  
    spec_plot                               html  
    spec_pointrange                         html  
    spec_popover                            html  
    spec_tooltip                            html  
    usepackage_latex                        html  
    xml_as_kable                            html  
    xtable2kable                            html  
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
> Adding '^\\.secret$' to './.Rbuildignore'
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `gm_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
Execution halted
*** arch - x64
Error: Can't get Google credentials.
Are you running gmailr in a non-interactive session? Consider:
  * Call `gm_auth()` directly with all necessary specifics.
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
* removing 'C:/Users/Jacob/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/kableExtra'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘kableExtra’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have some google oauth stuff in my .Rprofile which is the only reason I think those google warnings pop up, but it still weird that's in there.  I can't tell if I have rtools issues or if these google warnings are like completely halting these package installs.

And below is what a package install from binary looks like, no ugly warnings or errors being thrown.

```
package ‘kableExtra’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Jacob Yablonski\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6FZzqg\downloaded_packages
```

I don't know what else I'm missing.  Should I delete rtools40?  Am i missing a comma or backslash somewhere?  Is there some windows compiler file I need to install?  I don't have permissions to run .exe files but worst case scenario I guess I could contact IT to just get a fresh install of R & rtools35 again and go from there.  But if anybody has any idea on how to get this working so I can install packages from source I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Take that google stuff out of your .Rprofile. All your build tools look like. The only errors shown seem to come from the `gmailr` package interfering with R code that needs to be run to complete the install. They do seem to be clearly listed as errors, not just warnings so you need to make them go away.

Comment: Yep you were right on, the google stuff was causing the package installations to stop prematurely.  I have a similar setup on my desktop machine and never ran into that kind of issue, but good to know moving forward.  Thanks!